# Ruby: differences between () and [] in method parameters

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec for testing if a hash contains a key or not.

```
response_data = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
expect(response_data).to have_key('store_id')
expect(response_data).to have_key('store_name')
```

But on accident, I put square parentheses instead of rounded parentheses:

```
response_data = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
expect(response_data).to have_key['store_id']
expect(response_data).to have_key['store_name']
```

Which returns the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]'

Ruby doesn't throw an incorrect syntax exception, but instead an `undefined method` exception.

So how does ruby understand methods with square parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you call a method in ruby you use `()`. Sometimes you are allowed to use `[]` on a particular object and it works, but only because type of this object has `[]` method defined in its definition. for instance

```
class Foo
  def [](key)
    key
  end
end

# and later you can call:

foo = Foo.new
foo['anything']
```

Comment: Worth noting that lambdas, Methods, and other callable objects can be called using brackets, for example: `x = -> { ... }; x[]` and `m = 11.method(:to_s); m[16]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's syntactic sugar. `[]` and `[]=`  are methods defined for Array, Hash and other classes.
Given `a` an array, I think

```
a[0] = 5
```

is the same of

```
a.[]=(0, 5)
```

I tried in irb, it works :)

Comment: to clarify, `[]` and `[]=` are actually two separate methods on `Array`, check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D respectively

Answer (score 0):

Generally round brackets are used for specifying *arguments* and square brackets are for *indexing* things.

Example:

```
def is_a_method(a, b)
end

is_a_method(1,2)

is_a_hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
is_a_hash[:a]
```

They're not interchangeable. Like a lot of things in programming the exact characters matter.

These things can be stacked and combined:

```
JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
```

The result of the `JSON.parse(...)` method call is, in this case, a Hash data structure. Calling `['data']` on that pulls out an element from that structure.

In many cases the round brackets are optional, but in some cases they're best included for clarity. For example you can express that as this:

```
body = JSON.parse response.body
body['data']
```

Square brackets are not optional.